# How do I override style in a specific theme

Tags: wpf, themes, styles

I'm trying to override the default style of a base control (TextBox, ComboBox) in a theme-file.
Like this:

in themes/classic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

in themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I always get the defaulted style with no changes. I even tried it with a specific key 
like

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

and always use this key when declaring the control in xaml. Nothing seems to work.

If I put the style in the application.xaml file I have no problem but I want this style to be theme dependent.
By the way, it works well with my own usercontrols.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I know one solution could be to use a class to see wich theme I use and to use a trigger of somesort, but I really wanted to do this in xaml.

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the code of app.xaml?

Comment: <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero, Version=4.0.0.0,
                   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
                   ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml">
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

Answer (score 1):

Did you reference your theme somewhere?
e.g.

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="Test.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Simple Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Also, don't use the x:Key in themes unless it's just a sub-style that is referenced inside the theme by another style.

Comment: I did reference the theme-file from the aero-dll (look at the comment before this). I changed the assemblyinfo file like this: <Assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)> so wpf would use my extended theme-files (classic.xaml,aero.normalcolor.xaml, luna.metallic.xaml, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `ThemeInfo` mechanism is only used for controls defined in the same assembly.  What you want is to load theme-specific resources for controls that are not your own.  I haven't tested it but I think what you need is the [ThemeDictionary Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms752067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  A `ThemeDictionary` loads a theme-appropriate `ResourceDictionary` from an assembly.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a4479b0b-1e76-44ed-9f1f-1254608d4999) is someone who go it to work statically, which appears to be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are getting circular references. This is because you define a style with class XXX, but also use the same resource as base resource.

I have wrote a blog article about this a "long" time ago, it explains what to do:

http://blog.catenalogic.com/post/2009/07/20/Override-or-customize-WPF-themes-such-as-PresentationFrameworkAero.aspx

The trick is to define a style in the same resource dictionary with the key "DefaultTextBoxStyle", and then programatically add the styles with the right key ("{x:Type TextBox}" the to main application resource. This way, you avoid the circular references.

Comment: I've already seen your great blog. Since i'm stuck on the xaml-side, I will give the stylehelper class a go.

Comment: Just let us know if you need more help.

Comment: Your link is broken.  I found the right URL (http://geertvanhorrik.com/2009/07/20/override-or-customize-wpf-themes-such-as-presentationframework-aero/), but the zip file also 404's.

Comment: See https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/StyleHelper (for docs) and https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/develop/src/Catel.Extensions.Controls/Catel.Extensions.Controls.NET40/Windows/Helpers/StyleHelper.cs (for source)

Comment: Links are dead. It would be helpful if you included the code for StyleHelper here with examples :)